# Is static field of a class shared between tests when the class is parameterized?

Tags: java, junit, static, parameterized

I have a class which has static and non static fields. I parameterize this class for JUnit tests. 
Now I have doubts whether static fields are shared between tests or not. If @Parameterized annotation only helps to create many instances of the same class then I believe static fields are shared between tests, but if it creates different classes (for example, with adding some suffix to the class name in background) then every class will have its own static fields.
I tried to test it with this code, but without success:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Parametrized {
   public static String field1;
   public String field2;
   public int slp;

   public Parametrized (String str1, String str2, int slp) {
    this.field1 = str1;
    this.field2 = str2;
    this.slp = slp;
   }

   @Parameterized.Parameters ()
   public static List<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList( new Object[][] {{"1_static", "1_nonstatic", 5000}, {"2_static", "2_nonstatic", 2000}});
   }

   @Test
   public void test_static() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(field1);
    Thread.sleep(this.slp);
    System.out.println(field2);
    System.out.println(field1);
   }
}
```

Firstly, I noticed that the tests are not run in parallel, but one after another: I thought that was the main point of using @Parameterized - to run tests in parallel.

Secondly, because it was run one after another it did not help me to find out whether static fields are shared.

Comment: It is also not clear how it works if tests are run with Maven's SureFire plugin - will it create different copies of parametrized class in background with each having its own static objects?

Answer (score 3):

Adding an annotation doesn't change how Java works. a `static` field is still a static field.

This is not for running tests in parallel as they might interfere with each other. e.g. a shared resource like a static field.

BTW if you are setting a static field in a constructor you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: Regarding setting a static field in a constructor - I did it on purpose to test if static fields are shared. That is why I added a sleep there: I wanted to set it with first data, then change it with the second set of data, and then check its value  from the 1st set of data to see if it was changed by the second set of data. But because it was run not in parallel, but sequentially - it did not make a lot of sense. That is why I came here to clarify what is going on.

Comment: @user6419217 the static field is still static. You should only use it for fields which don't change across tests so it doesn't matter.  Interference between tests is a real pain to debug.